# jquery fullcalendar - strange issue with event data

Tags: json, jquery, fullcalendar, kohana-3

for some reason my event data isn't working correctly with jquery fullcalendar when I load it via ajax. However, the ajax request is definitely returning correctly formatted JSON data - if i simply copy and paste the returned data and hard code it into the event source when initialising the calendar, all works correctly! Here is my code - any idea what the issue could be?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // This is the data returned by the AJAX request - works fine when hard coded
    var data = 
            [{"title":"Test Event","description":"<p>Tester<\/p>","start":"1329264000","end":"1329264000","className":"sport junior_school"}];        

        var cal = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            editable: true,
            eventSources: [
                '<?php echo Url::base()?>school-calendar/fetch_events'
                //data
            ]
        });  
});
```

Comment: Define "isn't working correctly."  Also, show us the _actual_ output of the PHP code.

Comment: The event isn't showing in the calendar when using the URL as the event source. When hard coding the JSON response, as shown in the `data` var in the pasted code above, the event does show on the calendar. The PHP output is the same as above apart from where the Url is generated using Url::base

Comment: Is this using Kohana to produce the URL ( http://docs.kohanaphp.com/helpers/url )? If so, shouldn't it be `url::base()` as opposed to the upper-cased `U` in `Url::base`?

Comment: Ah yes, you recognised that it was Kohana :) In Kohana 3, the convention is to use uppercase U in Url::. Anyway, the correct URL is generated and in Firebug I can see the AJAX request to that URL, and the JSON response

Comment: Ahh, Kohana 3, aren't you progressive...? ;)  Ok, what do the response headers look like, and does jQuery give any indication of failed JSON parse?

Comment: Everything looks ok in the response headers. Here's a [link](http://staging.jem-digital.com/lathallan/public_html/school-calendar) - actually it looks like there's an XHR request for the full page, as well as the event data. Maybe that's the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the page you linked from the comment discussion, you are not using the code you showed in your post. In your actual page, you are setting a  var named `data` to the return value of your call to `$.getJSON`, and then passing `data` into `fullCalendar` as an event source.

```
var data = $.getJSON('http://staging.jem-digital.com/lathallan/public_html/school-calendar/fetch_events');

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //blah blah...
    eventSources: [
        data
    ],
    //blah blah...
});
```

The problem with that is that `$.getJSON` returns a [jQXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) object, and fullCalendar cannot take such an object as a data source.

In Firebug, if I empty your `#calendar` element and run the following, I get an event on the calendar:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
  },
  editable: true,
  eventSources: [
    'http://staging.jem-digital.com/lathallan/public_html/school-calendar/fetch_events'
  ],
  eventRender: function (event, element) {
    element.qtip({
      content: {
        text: formatEvent(event), 
        title: {
          text: event.title,
          button: true
        }
      },
      show: {
        event: 'click', // Show it on click...
        solo: true // ...and hide all other tooltips...
      },
      hide: false,
      style: {
        classes: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-rounded'
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Or, if you really want to run your own AJAX call, then you need to pass data to the calendar in the success callback of the `$.getJSON`. Here is one variation of such a thing:

```
$.getJSON('http://staging.jem-digital.com/lathallan/public_html/school-calendar/fetch_events', function (data) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        //blah blah...
        eventSources: [
            data
        ],
        //blah blah...
    });
});
```

I see little benefit to the latter, however.

Comment: Based on the changes to the source of your site, and the event I now sew on your calendar at load, I assume this was the issue?

Comment: I'd actually not fully updated the JS on the link I posted - I was testing it locally yesterday. You're correct about using getJSON - I'd experimented with that yesterday before trying just with .get, and also the approach you've laid out above (first one). Strangely, the issue only seems to be locally on my machine, the remote versio of the site is working correctly. A touch confusing! Thanks for your help JAAulde.